# Restore backup to new SharePoint 2010 server

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell, restore

this issue is piggybacking on a previous Issue I had.  I just set up a new SharePoint server for testing purposes, and I want to import the back ups of our production server for obvious reasons.  However, when I run the following script in SharePoint 2010 Management Shell I get hit with the error:

The backup file should be restored to a server with version '4.0.145.0' or later.

Script I run:

```
    restore-SPsite -Identity http://SPtesting:<port number> -path "c:\SharePoint Backups\<backup file>.bak" -force
```

In my previous post about this issue I was getting a different version number which I took care of.  In my research the current version number being thrown at me is in regards to the content database.  However, when I check the production server to the test server all the versions are the same.

**Test server:**

Database Schema Versions

Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence Current Schema Version: 4.1.9.0, Maximum Schema Version: 4.1.9.0

Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence2 Current Schema Version: 4.1.3.0, Maximum Schema Version: 4.1.3.0

Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase Current Schema Version: 14.0.6106.5002, Maximum Schema Version: 14.0.6106.5002

**Production Server:**

Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence Current Schema Version: 4.1.9.0, Maximum Schema Version: 4.1.9.0

Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence2 Current Schema Version: 4.1.3.0, Maximum Schema Version: 4.1.3.0

Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase Current Schema Version: 14.0.6106.5002, Maximum Schema Version: 14.0.6106.5002

Also, when I ran an upgrade on my test server I was told there are no updates available to upgrade.

I did make a site collection with the same name as the one I am trying to restore.

my question(s) are:

1) What steps/requirements am I missing?

2) Am I going about this all wrong?

3) How do I get these backups up and running on my test server?

Link to my previous question:

[different version error when restoring a SharePoint site collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111935/different-version-error-when-restoring-a-sharepoint-site-collection)

Comment: both test and production farm are using the sharepoint foundation?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I am sorry, looking at both the production/test servers under manage servers in Farm both state that the SharePoint Products Installed are "Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010" but for both the services running are "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Database" (With various other services)

Comment: services really doesn't matter...did you get the fresh backup of site collection from Production? what method you use for backup?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I did get a fresh backup from the production server, backups are run nightly.  all I know off hand about how the back ups are made is that it is done through powershell.  To find out more I would have to ask our system admin tomorrow morning.

Comment: Is it sharepoint site collection backup or sql content db backup?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE It is a SharePoint site collection back up, I actually have one backup for each site collection that I want to bring to the new test server.

Comment: can you share the exact error

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Sorry, its been a very hectic today. but here is a link to an image of the error message.  

http://i.imgur.com/PdUuOtO.png

I edited out the name of the backup file for security purposes.

Comment: did you run the config wizard on the test server? run this on the test server...Stsadm -o localupgradestatus

Comment: also make sure both test and prod having the same sharepoint product...follow this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mimorr/archive/2012/06/22/determine-which-sharepoint-2010-products-and-skus-are-installed.aspx

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I did run the config wizard on the test server, however I did run your command and everything went smoothly, but still could not import the site collections.  Looking at the production server it has:
SharePoint Foundation 2010, SharePoint Server 2010 Enterprise, and Office Web Companions 2010.  The test server had the same products minus the Web Companions.

Comment: I am not sure why this is throwing error, did you try Content Database Backup? also can you share the ULS logs? i am just making sure...you are taking backup(not export) from production and restore(not import) on test server.